# BudgetOrderService getBillingAccounts вовзвращает null

Tags: php, google-adwords

Все здравствуйте!
Помогите пожалуйста разобраться почему получаю null.

```
        $oAuth2Credential = (new OAuth2TokenBuilder())
        ->withClientId($scripts_params["google_adwords"]["client_id"])
        ->withClientSecret($scripts_params["google_adwords"]["client_secret"])
        ->withRefreshToken($params["refresh_token"])
        ->build();
    $session = (new AdWordsSessionBuilder())
        ->withOAuth2Credential($oAuth2Credential)
        ->withClientCustomerId($params["clientCustomerId"])
        ->withDeveloperToken($params["developerToken"])
        ->build();

    $AdWordsHeaderHandler = new AdwordsHeaderHandler();
    $AdWordsHeaderHandler->generateHttpHeaders($session);
    $SoapLogMessageFormatter = new SoapLogMessageFormatter();
    $AdWordsServiceDescriptor = new AdWordsServiceDescriptor(BudgetOrderService::class);
    $AdsSoapClientFactory = new AdsSoapClientFactory($SoapLogMessageFormatter);
    $soapClient = $AdsSoapClientFactory->generateSoapClient($session, $AdWordsHeaderHandler, $AdWordsServiceDescriptor);
    var_dump($soapClient->getBillingAccounts());
```

В кратце: Есть управляющий аккаунт, к которому подключены 2 других аккаунта. С этих аккаунтов нужно получать текущий остаток на счете. Я хочу взять все переведенные на счет суммы, сложить их и вычесть то что потрачено. Если кто-то знает более приемлемое решение, напишите пожалуйста.

Comment: Всем спасибо, я разобрался.